# WooCommerce customer logout issue with .htpasswd

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

We set login authentication with .htpasswd for https://website.test/wp-admin/ and https://website.test/wp-login.php file so whenever a user wants to send a request to that page or file he has to enter an authentication username and password. We did this to improve the website's admin panel security.

**The problem** is when a customer wants to logout from https://website.test/my-account/ he has to enter the authentication information.

We're using `wc_logout_url()` for logout url.

I think the problem is when a customer clicks on `wc_logout_url()` he requests to wp-login.php file so the server forced him to enter the authentication information.

Do you have any idea to fix this issue?
We're using Nginx if it helps.

Comment: If this is really happening, then the `wc_logout_url()` must be also logging out the app server authentication, which is really weird. Could you share some info about this config in your nginx?

Comment: @bpanatta Thank you so much for the reply. 
Honestly, we're using a managed WordPress server so I don't have the access to the server. 
They set a .htpasswd for the wp-login.php and wp-admin folder. 
I'm pretty sure when a customer wants to logout, it sends a request to the wp-login.php file. 
I guess I have to create our own logout function, yes?

Comment: Yes, you are right when you are saying that you need to create your own function for logout and not redirect that to any of your protected routes(nginx auth). If you face problems applying that solution, second approach to resolve the same query is to remove the auth from login file as in most of the websites login features doesn't require protection instead create another (,php) file and extract out all the code from login.php which you need to protect and apply nginx auth on that file.